# looking for suggestion for better solution

Tags: business-logic

I'm trying to find an answer to the issue below.

We have an appointment application. A task table and an appointment table are both included in the appointment application. A request for an appointment may involve several tasks. When an appointment is submitted, it is a business need that the user receive an email including all child tasks associated with that appointment.

new child task record can be added to  existing appointment. If a new task is added to an existing appointment record, this time system must send an email with a content that contains all task ids.

Could you please advise how this might be handled logically?

Comment: Your question is too broad and no code was provided

Comment: @drum I am looking for a better approach or logic to  implement development i have not started yet